# Kind of elementary symmetric product

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-polynomials

I have the following polynomial in the variables $A_1, A_2, ..., A_n;B_1, ...,B_n:$

$ f(A_1, A_2, ..., A_n;B_1, ...,B_n) = A_1B_2B_3...B_n + B_1A_2B_3...B_n + ...+B_1...B_{n-1}A_n$

Without the $A_j$ I would get the elementary symmetric polynomial $e_{n - 1}(B_1, ...B_n)$, hence the question: Is there a way to rewrite f into a nicer form, maybe using symmetric polynomials, or generating functions?

Comment: Don't know that it counts as a "*nicer form*" but $\,f\,$ satisfies the identity $\,f(A_1B_1, \,A_2B_2, \dots, \,A_nB_n;\,B_1, \,B_2, \dots ,B_n)$ $= B_1B_2\dots B_n \cdot \left(A_1+A_2+\dots+A_n\right)\,$.